# Did Green Arrow ever acknowledge Batman as a "role model"

Tags: dc, comics, batman, green-arrow

Way back when Green Arrow was created, DC was basically looking to create a "second Batman".  So they made Oliver Queen a billionaire, gave him a boy sidekick, gave him an Arrow-car, etc, etc.

My question is: Was there ever an "in-universe" acknowledgement by Green Arrow of how much he basically followed the "Batman model" in his crime-fighting career? Pre-crisis, post-crisis, whenever.

Answer (score 7):

There was an acknowledgement of the situation by Batman, at least.  This was quite a bit later than I originally thought, in the 2001 *[Green Arrow:  Quiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_(comics))* series.*  When the topics of the erstwhile Arrow-Plane and Arrow-Cave come up in conversation between the two superheroes, Batman says:  "Good Lord—did you *ever* have an original thought back then?"  (As you can see, Oliver looks a bit annoyed by the question.)

[image: Batman gets snarky.]

The issue may also have been discussed when the characters crossed over for the first time, in the 1940s or 1950s.  Unlike the first Batman-Superman crossover in *Superman* no. 76, early Batman-Green Arrow crossovers were not extensively reprinted.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Arrow), the similarity between the heroes in Green Arrow's earliest days was practically comical:

> He retooled the concept into a superhero archer with obvious Batman influences. 
>    These include Green Arrow's sidekick Speedy, his use of an Arrowcar and Arrow-Plane for transportation, his use of an Arrow-Cave as his headquarters, his alter ego as a wealthy playboy, the use of an Arrow-Signal to summon him, as well as a clown-like arch foe named Bull's Eye, similar to Batman's arch-foe, the Joker.

*Thanks to FuzzyBoots for locating this.

Comment: That's good, but I'm going to hold out for a specific cite.

Comment: *Green Arrow: Quiver* https://whatculture.com/comics/batman-80-greatest-ever-moments?page=24